# How to add a dropdown menu (or any list of links!) to a Sharepoint Promoted Links tile?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, dropdown, promoted-links

I'd like to have one of the tiles of my Promoted Links to open a dropdown menu. Or any kind of menu really.

Basically, what I need is that when the user clicks on the tile, a list of links appears, so that the user can choose which one.

How could I do that?

Comment: Whether you refer to quick links in the modern page of SharePoint Online?

Comment: We're not using Modern SharePoint, but I could try to pitch the idea. Is there a way to put a list of links of a floating context menu in modern SharePoint?